# Circular Sector inscribed inside a similar sector

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

I was just thinking about this question. When can a circular sector be inscribed inside a similar  sector (with an equal angle and of course a larger radius)?

I don't have a diagram for this, but I don't think it's too complicated. I tried connecting the smaller radius to the point of tangency, but got nowhere. Thanks for the help.

[Sketch of Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9K4b.png)

Comment: Isn't it trivial that you always can?

Comment: I meant with there being 5 points shared points between the two sectors, so 60 degrees wouldn't work.

Comment: Where does this "five points" rule come into it? You need to make the question a lot clearer.

Comment: I've attached a figure of what it looks like. It's a hand sketch because I thought of the problem; it's not from a book or online resource.

Comment: @mathboy, It is possible.

Answer (score 0):

$AB=BC$

$AC=CE=2BC=2DE$

$tan(CDE)=\dfrac{2}{1}$

$\angle EDF=2tan^{-1}(2)≈2×63.435≈126.87°$
[image]